# Write and display error message for live website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website, At the moment when i run it off my local host every thing works fine.

I have uploaded this website to fireFTP and can now access my website online.

The website does not preform the same as when hosted on local host and i cant find the errors as my website does not break.

I would like to do some testing and am wanting to know how to display an error message??

I would like to display the error message like this:

[image]

But with a custom message like, "code stepped into method writeToSpreadSheet".

This way i could find where my code gets to and pin point whats going wrong.

Comment: You can also use the `HandleError`-filter, [here's a quick post about it](http://www.aspnet101.com/2011/01/asp-net-mvc-error-handling-using-the-handleerror-filter/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `show detailed error messages` in IIS settings, see the link below for a short tutorial about how to do it.

[IIS7 : HOW TO enable the detailed error messages for the website while browsed from for the client browsers?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx)

Comment: That's if he has access to the IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in web.config inside  so you dont have
to touch the IIS configuration:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error redirect="error404.html" statusCode="404" />        
</customErrors>
```

Change the error404.html for your desired html page.
When some page is not found user will be redirected there